# Calculating total lengh of selected feature in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

I have selected some polylines on my map. Now I would like to know the total lengh of those. I've found great explanation about "calculate geometry" tool. Which do exactly that BUT modifying your table (adding or updating a field).
I would like only to see the result not to store it somewhere.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you have an existing field with length stored in it, like Shape_Length or similar?  If so, you can open the attribute table and right-click that column select 'Statistics' and it will generate stats for the field, including sum of length for all selected features.

Comment: For most database storage types (file geodatabase, enterprise geodatabase) the length of features is automatically included as as extra field already ('Shape_Length').  So the "calculate geometry" is unnecessary for these data stores.  If you are using Shapefiles, then you would need to manually add a field and run "calculate geometry" on that field, OR use the "add geometry attributes" field (which does a similar thing).  What type of data store are these features in?  Do they already have such an attribute?

Comment: I do not have a field of that type, and this database is shared between multiple users. Therefore I can't add a specific new row. I would like only to see the result once, not permanently store it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run this snippet of Python in the Python window. Just update the `lines` to point at your actual layer in the Contents page. Note the code /1000, assuming your distances are in Meters and you want KMs. You may need to update this to more accurately reflect your data.

```py
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("lines", ["SHAPE@LENGTH"]) as c:
    total = 0
    for r in c:
        seg = r[0] /1000
        print("distance: {:0.2f}".format(seg))
        total += seg
    print("Total distance: {:0.2f}".format(total))
```

Comment: This is the perfect answer. Thank you.
Just for the other, no special character for the alias of your layer otherwise you will get an error.

Comment: @Arthur, if you are only interested in the total and not printing out the segment values, the code can be collapsed to a single line after defining the cursor by using [Python's built-in Sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function: `print(f"Total distance: {sum(len for len, in c)/1000:0.2f}")`